# Salesforce DX: Client identifier invalid

Tags: salesforcedx

I am trying to configure CI on my desktop as per [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/sfdx_travis_ci/units/sfdx_travis_ci_connected_app) Trailhead module

But the issue I am facing is, i am getting the error:

```
force:auth:jwt:grant: client identifier invalid
```

after running the command

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid ${CONSUMER_KEY}  --username ${HUB_USERNAME}
      --jwtkeyfile ${JWT_KEY_FILE} --setdefaultdevhubusername
```

although I have set the envionment variables using `set` command, I am not sure what could be the issue. All the variables are set correct as per my knowledge.

I am not sure what could be the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my surprise, I hardcoded the values instead of using environment variables, and added and I got connected.

Although I used the following command:

```
set CONSUMER_KEY=<connected app consumer key>
set JWT_KEY_FILE=<your server.key path>
set HUB_USERNAME=<your Dev Hub username>
```

since, I am using Windows PC which does not support `export`, i opted to use `set` instead.